# Route 53 - Subdomain directing to wrong instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

OK, so I have three ELBs, and three subdomains in the same hosted zone. Each ELB load balances a different environment--one is prod, one is staging, one is a second staging environment. I've got three CNAMEs configured in Route 53, each directing to one of the ELBs, like this:

```
mysite.com = directs to ELB for prod (let's call it ProdELB)
staging.mysite.com = directs to StagingELB
newtest.staging.mysite.com = directs to NewStagingELB
```

The first two work fine.. however, the last one won't work.. it keeps mixing it up with the second one. Whenever I type newtest.staging.mysite.com into my browser, my browser responds by loading a page from staging.mysite.com instead, as though it's somehow redirecting to the second ELB instead of the third one. But there's nothing in my Route 53 to tell it to do that.

This even happens if I try to load the ELB domain name directly; ie. typing http://NewStagingELB.elb.aws.amazon.com in my browser will also cause staging.mysite.com to load. Even loading one of the instance IPs directly causes my browser to load the staging.mysite.com site.. what the heck is going on?

It's only the browser that does this.. pinging newtest.staging.mysite.com returns the correct ELB. It's also not a cache or cookie issue or anything like that because I've tried on multiple browsers including on my cell phone over data.

How do I get newtest.staging.mysite.com to actually direct to the right ELB?

Comment: Look into your NewStaging (newtest) webserver settings, or application itself, that is where the redirect seems to come from

Comment: Aha! that was it.. damn devs not telling me about tomcat connector settings. No wonder I wasn't figuring this out, kept looking at it from an ops perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a software-related problem.. newtest's tomcat's server.xml's Connector had proxyName and proxyPort settings that were stuck to the second instance.